# How do I determine the number of concurrent requests from an async httpclient during execution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have a simple console application which looks like this:

```
    private static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private static async Task<HttpStatusCode> AccessTheWebAsync()
    {            
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com").ConfigureAwait(false);
        return response.StatusCode;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            tasks.Add(AccessTheWebAsync());
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        foreach (Task<HttpStatusCode> t in tasks)
            sb.Append((int)t.Result).Append(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());            
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Run Completed, Time elapsed: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here I initiate 10 async web requests and collect the response codes when the requests are completed and list them.

1. **Question**: Is it possible to use VS2012 to debug the app in such a way where I can determine the number of concurrent web requests that are happening at any given point during execution?

Reason being is I found out there's something you can change on the `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "10" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

But, I've not a good way to determine if this is actually working or not.

1. Do servers set this limit?
2. Does the OS set this limit?
3. Does this app config and/or .NET set this limit?

Comment: not that there's anything wrong with what you're doing now, but just FYI, the HttpClient can be used for multiple concurrent calls on its own - you don't need to have N different instances of it for N different calls.

Comment: @JamesManning OK, I made it a field instead. Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to programmatically track this (for instance, for display in a UI) or just to verify expected behavior?

Comment: To clarify - if it's to just see the behavior, I would use and trust Fiddler instead of anything inside the app itself. :)

Comment: Trying to see how many simultaneous GET requests can be issued, but I don't know where this limit is imposed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use VS2012 to debug the app in such a way where I
>   can determine the number of concurrent web requests that are happening
>   at any given point during execution?

Yes, surely. Use [Parallel Tasks](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ParallelTasksWindow.aspx) and [Parallel Stacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554943.aspx) windows, they are very good.

> 1. Do servers set this limit?
> 2. Does the OS set this limit?
> 3. Does this app config and/or .NET set this limit?

The setting specifies [the maximum number of connections to a network host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) and can be set on the machine or application level. A server could set a connection limit for the clients as well but that's not related to `maxconnection` attribute.

In your example the actual maximum number of connections can also be limited by thread pool settings. Have a look at [this KB entry](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=821268) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static int variable and use Interlock Increment / Decrement. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd78zt0c.aspx